# Combining output from 2 mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im pretty new to PHP (used to do .NET things) and i have some trouble with some array stuff.

What I want to achieve is to combine to arrays lists retrieved from my Mysql.

Right now i first iterate through my mysql result and copy all these Idś into arrays and then i make a nested foreach to combine all of them.

I wonder if there is a shortcut/smarter way to do this?

Looks like this

```
 $queryBodytext = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BodyTexts WHERE CampaignId = " . $campaign_id );

 $queryImages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Images WHERE CampaignId = " . $campaign_id );

 $bodytext_ids = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryBodytext))
 {
    $bodytext_ids[] = $row['Id'];      
 }

 $image_ids = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryImages))
 {
    $image_ids[] = $row['Id'];       
 }

 foreach ($image_ids as $imgId) {
     foreach ($bodytext_ids as $bodyId) {
         echo 'Body id: ' . $bodyId . '. ImageId: '. $imgId . '<br />';
     }
 }
```

Comment: So if you have 5 body and 4 image you want to print 4 x 5 = 20 rows?

Answer (score 1):

Why not combine them in the query itself?

```
SELECT b.Id AS BodyTextId, i.Id AS ImageId
FROM BodyTexts b
INNER JOIN Images i ON b.CampaignId = i.CampaignId
WHERE CampaignId = {$campaignid}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a join in your SQL so that the results come back as a single list?  Then adjust your looping to support that.  The SQL would be:

$query = mysql_query("SELECT BodyTexts.Id As BodyTextsId, Images.Id as ImagesId FROM BodyTexts JOIN Images on BodyTexts.CampaignId = Images.CampaignId WHERE CampaignId = " . $campaign_id );

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a UNION?

Here's an example: [UNION example](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php)